# split text but keep the delimiter at end of sentence with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a text like `"Hi.My name is jeff!How are you?fine"`.

I want to split this text based on `.` and `?` with regex to get output like this:

```
['Hi.', 'My name is jeff!How are you?', 'fine']
```

**I tried** `$` and also `\Z`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
string = "Hi.My name is jeff!How are you?fine"
print(re.split(r"(?<=[.?])", string))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolau4pCgzL13BVkHJI1PPt1IhLzE3VSGzWCErNS1N0SO/XCGxKFWhMr/UPi0zL1WJqwCoukSjKFWvuCAnE8hQ0rC3sY3Ws4/VVNJRgJilqcn1/z8A). Also, see [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/bjqkyh/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [.?]                     any character of: '.', '?'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
```